# "this" doesn't work in click event handler

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I have attached a click event handler to my ChartJS-derived component, like this:

```
export default {
  extends: HorizontalBar,
  data() {
    return {
      my_data: [],
      options: {
        onClick: function(event, args) {
           //need to access my_data here
        }
      },
    };
  },
}
```

I need to access one of my `data` members inside the handler. Unfortunately, `this.my_data` doesn't work here. ChartJS documentation tells me that this event is called in the context of the Chart component, not my Vue component. How can I get access to `my_data`?

### update

So I'm now using @Dan's way of defining the handler:

```
export default {
  extends: HorizontalBar,
  data() {
    return {
      my_data: [],
      options: {
        onClick: this.ClickHandler,
      },
    };
  },

  methods: {
    ClickHandler: function(event, args) {
      var datapoint = this.getElementAtEvent(event);
      var value = this.my_data[datapoint._datasetIndex];
    },
  }
}
```

The handler is called correctly, but `this` is now refering to my Vue component and therefore I do not have any reference to the `Chart` context to call its `getElementAtEvent`.

So if I declare it in front of `onClick` above, I get the Chart context in `this`, but no longer have access to `my_data`. If I use your way, I get `this.my_data`, but lose Chart context.

Comment: @Stephen Thomas's answer should work... You can combine Dan's and his answers, please see [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) for how his answer works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the handler into your `methods` object and then reference it from the chart `options` handler:

```js
data() {
  return {
    my_data: [],
    options: {
      onClick: this.ClickHandler,
    }
  };
},
methods: {
  ClickHandler: function(event, points) {
    // Here is how to access the chart
    const c = this._data._chart;
    const datapoint = c.getElementAtEvent(event)[0];
    const indexBar = datapoint._index;
    const indexSegment = datapoint._datasetIndex;
    // Do whatever with this.my_data, indexBar, and indexSegment
  }
}
```

The chart is accessible to the component through `this._data._chart`.

Comment: This looks promising, but what do I write in front of `onClick: ` now? Note that I need both the `Chart` object reference as well as Vue object reference. Note that I'm attaching the event handler in JS, not through HTML tag.

Comment: Can you show some related code or template?  It's not clear what else you want to achieve

Comment: Where is the chart context coming from?  It would be helpful to see how you were getting it before in the template.  (I've never looked at ChartJS or maybe I'd have a better understanding of that.)

Comment: ChartJS passes this context to the event handler automatically. It isn't fully documented, but you can see a brief note [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/events.html).

Comment: What do you see when you log `event` and `args`?  (Even without specifying any arguments to the handler)

Comment: Found this example, and indeed a component `method` is similarly passed.  Take a look at the `handle` method   https://jsfiddle.net/devjin0617/wc9r94wq/

Comment: `event` is a MouseClick event with all thsoe mouse related properties. `args` is the list of `ChartElement`s around the mouse position.

Comment: This was the my earlier approach. Problem with this method is that in my case (I'm using a Stacked Bar Chart), the second param of the handler gives me all 40 data points in an array, instead of just the one on which I clicked. I'm not sure if this has something to do with the chart type I'm using (because it works correctly in the fiddle example u suggested), but this was why I had to switch to `getElementAtEvent` method that gives me exactly one element on which I click.

Comment: Thanks for the effort though. I'll keep trying in the morning. 2AM here. :)

Comment: Sure, I'll check it out a bit more too

Comment: I realized the chart must be accessible somewhere on the component. Checking the instance properties, I found it at `this._data._chart`. See the updated answer.  Then check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/7yu14td2/) where I took someone's stacked bar chart and rigged the click handler from the answer.  Clicking a segment logs the info to the console.

Comment: THAT'S THAT! `this._data._chart` was the thing I needed. As delicious as "garma-garam pikoray" on a rainy day. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Create a closure variable

```
data() {
    const vm = this;
    return {
      my_data: [],
      options: {
        onClick: function(event, args) {
           this.chartjs.something;
           vm.my_data[]
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Just found that this works as good as Dan's answer. Can't select more than one answer, but this definitely deserves an upvote.